# Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "V5TableName" does not exist

Tags: php, postgresql, zend-framework, zend-db, pgadmin-4

I am using an MVC framework (Zend) for my application and I want to find the total size of a table in PostgreSQL (including index). The table name is **"V5TableName"** - quotes included because table name is case sensitive. I have made sure that there is NO typo involved.

My code to get the table size is shown below:

```
public function getMyTableSize()
{
  $sql = "SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size( '\"V5TableName\"' ) );";

  /* Custom_Db is a custom library in my application which makes the PostgreSQL connection 
     and queries the database
   */
  $tableSize = Custom_Db::query($sql)->fetchColumn(); 

  return $tableSize;
}
```

When my application calls this function it returns the following error in my logs :

> ```
> [22-Apr-2020 09:42:37] PID:30849 ERR: SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "V5TableName" does not exist
> LINE 1: SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size( '"V5TableName...
>                                                       ^
> query was: SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size( '"V5TableName"' ) );
> ```

If I run this same query in pgAdmin4 it works perfectly fine returning the table size (for instance: 104Mb).

I have tried:

1. Removing and adding quotes to the table name in the code.
2. Appending the schema as prefix to the table name (example: `'public."V5TableName"'`).

NONE of the above seem to work. I am not sure what is going wrong over here.

I also tried to find the total database size in my application (db name: `MyDbName` - with mixed case spelling) and my query looked something like below:

```
$sql = "SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('MyDbName'))"; // this DID NOT WORK
```

So I changed it to the one shown below: (it worked)

```
$sql = "SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size( current_database() ))"; // this WORKED
```

I was wondering if there is something similar that could be done to find the table size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query *should* work. The use of double-quotes seems correct.

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('"V5TableName"'));
```

First make sure you are connecting to the **right database cluster** (a.k.a. "server"). It's defined by its data directory, or equally unambiguous by hostname and port number. Read the manual [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/creating-cluster.html) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ecpg-connect.html).

Then make sure you are connecting to the **right database** within that database cluster. A Postgres database cluster consists of 1-n databases. When connecting without specifying the actual database, you end up in the maintenance database named `postgres` by default. That's the most likely explanation. Check with:

```
SELECT current_database();
```

Then check for the **right table and schema name**:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_tables
WHERE tablename ~* 'V5TableName';  -- ~* matches case-insensitive
```

The first riddle should be solved at this point.

Check your DB spelling and possible near-duplicates with:

```
SELECT datname FROM pg_database;
```

The call is *without* double-quotes (like you tried correctly), but requires correct capitalization:

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('MyDbName'));
```

**Note the subtle difference** (as documented [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE)):

- `pg_database_size()` takes `oid` or **[`name`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html#DATATYPE-CHARACTER-SPECIAL-TABLE)**. So pass the case-sensitive database name ***without double-quotes***.
- `pg_total_relation_size()` takes **[`regclass`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html)**. So pass the case-sensitive relation name ***with double-quotes*** if you need to preserve capitalization.

`pg_database_size()` has to differ because there is no dedicated object identifier type for databases ([no <strike>`regdatabase`</strike>](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html)).

The gist of it: avoid double-quoted identifiers in Postgres if at all possible. It makes your life easier.

Comment: Thank you Erwin. It was more of a Zend issue than a Postgres one. Also the db name was MyDbName.

Comment: @als10: Database clusters do not have a name. Databases do. You must chose a database when connecting.